# Jhipster gateway call directly microservice

Tags: java, microservices, jhipster, jhipster-registry

I try to create a gateway G and a microservice M.
I find to call M directly (without knowing it's address and port) it's sufficient make a call like:

```
http://gatewayAddress/microserviceName/api/....
```

But if I do this, I have a "404 request cannot be processed"
Maybe I must setup something?

Comment: Have you started both G and M? Are you running in prod profile ? Which service discovery are you running: JHipster registry, Consul, ...?

Comment: Yes. Both Gateway and Microservice are running in dev profile. I see from JHipster registry.

Comment: The answer from Wayne seems right to me, see the value of zuul.prefix property in your application*.yml

Comment: zuul.prefix is empty (not defined in my application.yml of the Gateway). Is it correct?

Comment: Which version of JHipster?

Comment: JHipster v5.7.2

Comment: Are you able to see the microservice under the API in gateway?

Comment: Yes, I see them. Both bateway and microservice. If I call the microservice directly it goes http://address:port/api/...